# can not get this javascript to communicate with my css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

quick question.  I really would like the style for when someone is browsing in half screen width(and eventually on mobile) to snap to a smaller style class.  Right now i am trying to add the class "small" when the screen is smaller than ~700 px.  If someone could point out when my codepen isn't adjusting the class that would be fantastic. Thanks guys.

...also yes my codpen username is garvdaddy, dont bully me :P

html i am targeting: `<p id="content" >`

http://codepen.io/garvdaddy/full/EKZMXp/

Comment: This a problem that is usually solved by writing CSS Media Queries, any particular reason you would want to add the class with javascript, and not just target the screen width with @media screen and (max-width: 700px)?

Comment: CSS Media Queries.... Not a quick answer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: Media queries is certainly the way to go!

Comment: thanks everyone!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can adjust the width automatically using a small javascript function:

1. Add **id** attribute to the `<link>` element:

   `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="widescreen.css" id="link1"/>`
2. We need events on which we call functions, so add attributes **onload** and **onresize** to `<body>`

   `<body onresize="f()" onload="f()">
   ...
   </body>`
3. Finally add the javascript function that will handle the changes on the page

   `<script>
   function f(){
   if(document.body.clientWidth<700)
   //condition which checks if the Width of page is less than 700
   {document.getElementById("link1").setAttribute("href","mobileresolution.css");}
   //if yes, than, with help of function .getElementById we fetch element with id="link1" and change its attribute’s href value to "mobileresolution.css"
   else
   {document.getElementById("link1").setAttribute("href","widescreen.css");}
   //if the width of the page is not less than 700 then href’s value is "widescreen.css"
   }
   <script>`

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
   <script>
    if( $(window).width() < 700)
    {
      $('p#content').addClass("small");
    }  
    </script>
```

Comment: `$(window).width()` and media queries do line up due to inconsistencies in different browsers related to the scroll bar.  It is not best practice to use code like this.  Instead, you should check a particular css property of a certain element... the width of the element, for example.