# When minimizing my browser my websites menus stack??! tried everything (css)

Tags: css, wordpress

I worked very hard on my first website! I can't seem to figure this one out. I have checked the custom css. And I still can figure out how to fix this problem. Really hope you guys can help because it makes the website look very bad!

www.martinfisherphotography.com is the website.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to use bootstrap. If you do not have enough experience with it go to point #2
2. Use javascript onLoad(); and onResize(); functions. I have been talking about this earlier here:

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36091978/can-not-get-this-javascript-to-communicate-with-my-css/36092260#36092260`

Comment: I don't think the go-to answer should be about switching framework completely, bootstrap is not the answer to all CSS related issues. It's definitely nicely responsive out the box but that's not what this question is asking for. Also why the recommendation about Javascript when media queries are available and are the intended resource to respond to smaller screens and size changes?

Recommend removing the backticks from your answer as they just stop   your link becoming a clickable link.